# How to detect the token of + from - in a parse

Tags: c, parsing, lexical-analysis

Let's say I have the following expression that I want to parse:

```
+++4+++---5+++6
```

And we have the following operators:

- `++` `--` postfix increment/decrement. Precedence 10, L-t-R.
- `++` `--` prefix increment/decrement.  Precedence 8, R-t-L.
- `+` `-` unary plus/mins. Precedence 8, R-t-L.
- `+` `-` addition/subtraction. Precedence 6, L-t-R.

How would I go about parsing the above to get the proper parse tree? For example, how would I tell where one token starts and another ends? So far I've stubbed it out with the following but I'm not sure where to go next with detecting a `++` vs `+`.

```
char *str = "+++4+++---5+++6";
size_t len = strlen(str);

for(char letter, i=0;i<len;) {
    switch(letter) {
       case('+') {

       } case('-') {

       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Remember that lexical analysis comes first, *then* parsing.  And the rule in C is that lexical analysis is "greedy", always finds the longest token it can.  For example, `x+++++x` comes out as the token string `x` `++` `++` `+` `x`, and is therefore a parse failure (and even though `x ++ + ++ x` would be parseable, albeit undefined).

Comment: @SteveSummit why would `x+++++x` fail? Couldn't that convert to `x` `+` `++` `++` `x`. Or does C just grab the largest token and cannot backtrack (like a regular expression could) to find a match?

Comment: @0___________ could you explain what you mean by write the grammar rules? These are C rules.

Comment: @David542 Yes.  "Grab the largest token".  That's exactly what I'm saying.  There is no backtracking in C lexical analysis.  (But lexical analysis is *not* parsing; that comes later.)

Comment: @David542 Also I think you'll find that `x` `+` `++` `++` `x` is a parse error also.

Comment: @0___________ "Extract the tokens knowing the grammar" isn't how C parsers work. As Steve says, it's the greediness of tokenization that makes this tractable. The grammar rules don't inform tokenization.

Comment: @JohnKugelman I see, so in that case, is the first comment incorrect to write the grammar rules? Meaning, we extract the tokens before knowing/caring about the grammar?

Comment: @david: mostly. The one big exception is `#include <stdlib.h>` which is two tokens,

Comment: @David542 Correct. Tokens first, grammar later. Keep in mind, this is *assuming you're following C's tokenization rules*. Tokenizers don't have to be greedy, though most are since it's so much simpler.

Comment: @JohnKugelman I see -- what would be a language where the tokens aren't greedy?

Comment: I don't know of one.

Comment: @JohnKugelman to extract tokens you need to know the grammar of the language. To tokenize you need to know lexicall grammar. Later you need to know syntax and semantics grammar.

Comment: C tokenization is hard without the semantics (lexer hack)

Comment: @JohnKugelman: the classic example of a language which doesn't respect the longest token rule is Fortran. There are also languages like Common Lisp where tokenisation is performed by a collection of character macros, which can be replaced on the fly. Most modern languages are "longest token with exceptions": `<::` and `>>` in C++; `2..9` in many languages with a range operator; regex literals in JavaScript and other languages (competing with `/` and `/=`). And on and on.

Comment: Use `char str[] = "..."` and `strlen` will optimize.